# Conference title

Tags: titles, ieeetran

How can I ​add the conference title, date and venue only to the upper right-hand corner of the first page (title page) of your source document of IEEE conference paper in font size 9pt? It looks like the following:

```
IEEE PEDS 2015, Sydney, Australia 9 – 12 June 2015
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo Why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eso-pic` (or similar for ex, `tikz`) and put the text.

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyright[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{0.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){%
     \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont #1}}%
 }}%
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
\AtPageUpperMyright{#1}
}
}
```

and then use it like

```
\maketitle
\conf{IEEE PEDS 2015, Sydney, Australia 9 – 12 June 2015}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\title{Sample paper}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{author 1\\ Department 1}%
  %\IEEEauthorblockA{}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{author 2\\ Department 2}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Institution/university \\
    mail1,mail2,mail3,mail4} \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{author 3\\ Department 3}
  %\IEEEauthorblockA{}
}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyright[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{0.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){%
     \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont #1}}%
 }}%
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
\AtPageUpperMyright{#1}
}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\conf{IEEE PEDS 2015, Sydney, Australia 9 – 12 June 2015}

\begin{abstract}
We propose ...
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Broad band networks, quality of service, WDM.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple fancy header?

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\rhead{
\sffamily\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont 
IEEE PEDS 2015, Sydney, Australia 9 – 12 June 2015}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\title{The title}
\author{The author}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Lore ipsum, sample, fancyhdr
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```